# Request a page vía ajax but know what class had the body

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, jquery-selectors

I am tring to get the body class when getting the page vía ajax, like this:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log( $(data).find('body').length, $(data).filter('body').length );
});
```

when the data logs the full html code ( with doctype, head, body, .. )

Both of the logs will return `0`

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: try to `console.log( $(data) );` and you can see the actual jQuery object the data is making from the html.

Comment: The thing is that body isnt there... I must be missing something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery doesn't seem to like anything with a doctype or something like `$("<html><body>")`.  Not sure why or if this is a bug, but you can create your own document and create a jQuery collection from that.

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
doc.innerHTML = data;
var $doc = $(doc);
console.log($doc.find("body").length);
```

Comment: Nice! this works! any idea why `console.log($doc.find("body").className);` is returning an emtpy string? ( the body has a few classes )

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet `.find` also returns a jQuery collection, and `.className` is not a jQuery property.  You can use `.attr("class")` or just not use jQuery and go with `doc.querySelector("body").classList` (or `className`)